# how to access rails app runing inside docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, dockerfile, puma

I am using Dockerfile to build docker container for basic rails blog app.
here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.3

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN bundle install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD rails server -p 8000 -b 0.0.0.0
```

then I ran this command to build docker image

```
docker build -t blog .
```

and here is how I ran container from docker image

```
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRES_USER -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD --net=blog --name app -v $PWD:/usr/src/app -p 8000:8000 blog
```

after accessing logs from container I got this

```
docker logs app
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.6.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.3.8-p459), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

After googling 2 hours I got some click that its a conflict in rails 5.1 that run `tcp://0.0.0.0:3000` in rails. So I switched my application server from PUMA to WEBRICK.
now the docker logs app says:

```
docker logs app
[2018-12-06 12:30:10] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2018-12-06 12:30:10] INFO  ruby 2.3.8 (2018-10-18) [x86_64-linux]
[2018-12-06 12:30:10] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=8 port=3000
```

but the application is still not accessible from firefoix/chrom.
Please guide if I am doing something wrong.
TIA :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an off the cuff suggestion:

Try:

```
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRES_USER -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD --net=blog --name app -v $PWD:/usr/src/app -p 3000:3000 blog
```

If you can resolve that perhaps the following is not being applied as you expect.

```
EXPOSE 8000
CMD rails server -p 8000 -b 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: did you mean the -p 3000:3000 in docker run command have higher priority than than 

EXPOSE 8000
CMD rails server -p 8000 -b 0.0.0.0
mentioned Dockerfile.

Comment: I believe it does by the output of the docker logs, also bear in mind that there may exist a condition where the Dockerfile EXPOSE 8000 may not have been applied correctly, thereby you are relying on the run command to expose the correct port.

Comment: your are right !! I guess it could be achieved in dockerfile?